# UTF-8, Latin1 encoding in MySQL

Tags: mysql, vb.net, encoding, utf-8, latin1

I have a problem with encoding in MySQL database. This database is encoded in UTF-8. But in phpMyAdmin I see that records have something like that: `Ĺ`, `Ă`, `Ä` instead of my polish letters: `ł`, `ą`, `ę` etc.

In my vb.net code I try to get one of this records but *I want to receive a correct encoding record (with polish letter)*. What should I do to achieve that?

I've read that I should set charset to latin1 in my ConnectionString but it doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried setting the charset as `UTF-8` in your connection string? E.g. `Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;CharSet=utf8;`

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention about that in my post. I've tried and it didn't help

Comment: Are your .vb files saved with UTF-8 encoding? See here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dxfdkfke%28v=vs.110%29.aspx how to save a file with specific encoding in VS